# Use of conditional probability in group

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, group-theory, probability-theory, finite-groups

$\{1,-1,i,i^2\}=G$ is a finite cyclic group and $H =\{1,-1\}$ is a
Subgroup of G.

Order of $G$ is $4$

And order of $H$ is $2$

$G\cap H =\{1,-1\}$

$P(G \cap H)= ((\text{number of elements of } G \cap H)/\text{number of elements of }G)=2/4=1/2$

Here $G$ is sample space and $H$ is sub set of $G$ .So $H$ is an event of $G$.

$P(G|H)=P(G \cap H)/P(H)=(1/2)/(1/2)=1

Is it wrong ?

Comment: Do you mean $G = \{1,i,-1,-i \}$? I.e is $i$ the imaginary number?

Comment: If $i$ is what we think it is (and you still haven't answered @NoelLundström 's question) then $\{1,i\}$ is not a subgroup. And what has this got to do with groups?

Comment: Now I think H is subgroup H{1,-1} .Now what you say

Answer (score 1):

If $H\subseteq G$ or equivalently $G\cap H=H$ then if $P(H)>0$: $$P(G\mid H)=\frac{P(G\cap H)}{P(H)}=\frac{P(H)}{P(H)}=1$$

Comment: Same as my solutions but I have done one mistake P(H)=1/2 ok but can we take G is sample space and H is an event .and see whole work I have use probability in group is possible.or any problem???

Comment: Group $G$ has an underlying non-empty set so can serve as sample space. You also need a $\sigma$-algebra on this set and $H$ can be an element of that $\sigma$-algebra (making it an event).

Comment: G is finite and H also finite then sigma algebra is required?

Comment: Formally a sigma algebra but in finite case a common and natural choice is just the power set of the sample space. If only $H $ matters then you can also take $\{\varnothing, H,H^c,G\} $.

Comment: Plz say why Power set of H is necessary in this case. Or you mean that P(H)=1/4.according to power set.

Comment: I said nothing about the powerset of $H$. If you want the underlying set of group $G$ as sample space and $H$ as event then you need a $\sigma$-algebra on $G$ that contains $H$ as element. The largest possibility for that is $\mathcal P(G)$ (all subsets of $G$) and the smallest possibility is $\{\varnothing,H,H^{\complement},G\}$. Then further you need a probability measure $P$ on this $\sigma$-algebra defined by $A\mapsto |A|/|G|$.

Comment: BUT Probability of an event is equal to number of element of event divide by number of element of sample space P(H)=O(H)/O(G). is it possible??

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the prescription I gave in the last line of my former comment.